# How to console log pairs in array

Tags: javascript

For example I have this string `"()[]|}"` and I want to compare each characters with eachother, but first I can't get the loop to work correctly. For the first log it works correctly, but after instead of going +1 it should go +2 I believe so it doesn't start from `)`. How do can I do this properly?

```js
function isValid(s) {
    
  let temp = s.split("");

  for (let i = 0; i < s.length/2; i++) {
        console.log(temp[i], temp[i+1]);
  }
};

isValid("()[]|}");
```

I want to log this

```
( )
[ ]
| }
```

not

```
( )
) [
[ ]
```

Comment: Change `i++` to `i += 2` to count by 2 instead of 1.

Comment: Why do you need to split the string into an array? You can use `s[i]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is correct but your for loop is slightly off:

```js
for (let i = 0; i < s.length; i += 2) {
```

Loop while i is less than the length, but add **2** instead of 1.

```js
function isValid(s) {
    
  let temp = s.split("");

  for (let i = 0; i < s.length; i += 2) {
        console.log(temp[i], temp[i+1]);
  }
};

isValid("()[]|}");
```

Comment: I was doing i+2 and it was crashing there, now I see it has to be += 2

Comment: If you don't want to get `undefined` at the end when there are an odd number of characters, only loop until `s.length - 1`.

Answer (score 0):

If the question is 'how do I increment by two instead of by 1', use `i += 2` instead of `i++` (since the increment operator only increments by 1)